# concatenating variables in a string

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a simple image uploader in PHP, it is uploading images but for some reason it is adding the image in the 'uploads' directory instead of the folder within that directory.

The variable $uploaddir seems to be printing the correct string, I know this because I re-name the image using the $uploaddir and I can see the image is named correctly with the same name as a folder inside the 'uploads' folder.

Iv done a lot of searches on URL strings and variables but cant work this out.  Here is my code:

```
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}";

      $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

      echo "<p>";

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
      } else {
         echo "Upload failed";
      }
      echo "</p>";
```

Comment: You can simply use the .= operator for string concatenating. `$uploadfile .= basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is that you're constructing your file path with a typo in it**.

Assuming your file's name is hello.png, then your resulting `$uploadfile` is currently:

> uploads/usa_ny_foohello.png

Whereas you want:

> uploads/usa_ny_foo/hello.png

So, what about adding a `/` at the end of your $uploaddir?

```
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/";
```

Or **in a more proper way**, you can try this:

```
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Comment: @conor909 Glad to be of some help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `/`

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir .'/'. basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directory first

```
mkdir('uploads/'.$directoryname, 0777, true);
```

For example

```
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/";
if(!is_dir($uploaddir))
{
if (!mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Comment: sorry I didnt mention, the folders are created.

Comment: Then do this
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))

Answer (score 0):

You are missing backslash

```
$uploaddir = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/";
```

And you will probably need to create that directory first by

`mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true)`